# Oracle and Python - cx_Oracle DLL load failed

Tags: python, oracle, oracle10g, cx-oracle

Right I have Python 2.6.2 installed on my machine, I wish to access an Oracle 10g (10.2.0.1.0 to be precise) instance on the same network (not local machine)

I've installed the cx_Oracle module v5.0.4 from

http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/cx-oracle/cx_Oracle-5.0.4-10g.win32-py2.6.msi?download

However if I load the python interpreter this is what I get when I try to import cx_Oracle

```
>>> import cx_Oracle
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Paul

Comment: import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(host='1.11.18.41', user='rdr', password='rdr') curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select * from fx_Alarm")
print curs.description
for x in range(3,numrows): row = cursor.fetchall() print row[0] print row[1] print row[2]
curs.close()
conn.close() i have written this code.bt it says dll import error. would u pls tell me which exe shall I install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it seems I needed to install the client version of oracle 10g. It's all fixed now :o)